# jQuery Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object Object]

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am new to programming and so far I like it when things work, but when it doesn't work it drives me crazy, I am a new to this and I would greatly appreciate some good help on this.

I created a jQuery lightbox effect and looks like it works great on my local machine but I do get an Uncaught Error: Syntax error,

```
$("#"+panelID).parent().css({
```

unrecognized expression: #[object Object] when I run it on chrome and I don't know what exactly how to figure out the problem, the box displays but when I load it on my wordpress the opacity does not turn on?

http://jsfiddle.net/2dzasz1e/

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related with this line (and similar)

```
$(window).bind('resize',showOverlayBox);
```

Method `showOverlayBox` is expecting a `panel Id` but on windows resize, you'll get a `jQuery.Event` instance, what is not expected. You'll need to unify your logic to make that method consistent with different usage on your code.

Comment: Okay so what would be the best approach to fix this the correct way?